# svn checkout depth

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I have an SVN project with tree like this:

```
/project
    /dir1
        /subdir1
           -file1
           -file2
            .....
        -file1
        -file2
        .....
    /dir2
        -file1
        -file2
        .....
    /dir3
        /subdir1
           -file1
           -file2
            .....
        /subdir2
           -file1
           -file2
            .....
        /subdir3
           -file1
           -file2
            .....
        /subdir4
           -file1
           -file2
            .....
    /dir4
        -file1
        -file2
        .....
-file1
-file2
```

I need to checkout

- all files from /project
- full /dir1
- full /dir2
- full /dir4
- From /dir3 I need only /subdir1 and /subdir3

Can I checkout these files/folders using svn commandline with some kind of depth? 
If so how can I do it?
Can I add subdir2 to dir3 after a checkout?
How can I update working copy created this way? Will normal "svn up" command update only these folders or full update of project will be performed?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

What you need is called [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

In your case you can:

```
svn co --depth files file:///project project
cd project
svn up --set-depth infinity dir1 dir2 dir4
svn up --set-depth empty dir3
svn up --set-depth infinity dir3/subdir1 dir3/subdir3
```

> Can I add subdir2 to dir3 after a checkout?

Yes: `svn up --set-depth infinity dir3/subdir2`

> How can I update working copy created this way? Will normal "svn up"
>   command update only these folders or full update of project will be
>   performed?

Yes, `svn up` will update only these files and folders, that is update depth will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks a lot.So if I understand if a new folder (for example dir5) will be added to project it will not be updated. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, parent folder of dir5 has depth set to `files`, so new files will be updated, but not new folders.

Comment: If you want to automatically add new top-level subdirs, using `--depth immediates` instead of `--depth files` should do the trick.

Comment: Now I know where I did wrong in past - I used `co` again instead of `up` in your example, thanks.

Comment: Just found that `--set-depth` is required when the directory you are trying to update was created using `--depth immediates` (as its depth property is set to 'empty' as can be seen by `svn info`)

Answer (score 1):

1. `svn up --set-depth empty file/folder path`

- => it will delete the file from your system**

2. `svn up --set-depth infinity file/folder path`

- => it will regenerated the file from svn server to your local system**