# Conflicts during "svn update" from Windows command line

Tags: svn, command-line, skip, svn-checkout, sparse-checkout

I'm using VisualSVN Server for my back-end SVN server (if that matters).

Below are two sets of commands.  The first set creates a folder and then checks out a folder in SVN to that newly created Windows folder.  The second set (single command) is giving a conflict error, but I do not know why.  I'm trying to do a sparse checkout and just check out two folders.  Ideally I would like the files under those two folders in addition (--set-depth immediates), but I have not gotten that far.  I looked at using TortoseProc.exe, but that API does not provide sufficient commands to do this from what I read.  If you know how to resolve this issue using svn commands, let me know.  I've tried several different variations of `svn checkout`, `svn update`, `svn up`, and a combination thereof.

The folder was created, and the `.svn` folder was created in that `_TEST` folder in Windows.  So I've verified the 1st set of commands.

**1st set of commands:**

```
K:
cd "K:\Projects\PRJ-71\"
mkdir "_TEST"
svn checkout --depth empty "https://example.com:8443/svn/docs/objects/trunk/" "_TEST"
```

**2nd set of commands:**

```
K:\Projects\PRJ-71>svn update --set-depth empty _TEST/NZ/F_CORPORATION_SIZE
K:\Projects\PRJ-71>svn update --set-depth empty _TEST/NZ/F_COVERAGE_MEMBER
```

**2nd set of commands (Errored on 1st command):**

```
K:\Projects\PRJ-71>svn update --set-depth empty _TEST/NZ/F_CORPORATION_SIZE

Skipped '\_TEST\NZ\F_CORPORATION_SIZE'
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

## EDIT (comment request):

[image]

Comment: Referenced this during troubleshooting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650156/svn-checkout-depth

Comment: Referenced this during troubleshooting: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html

Comment: What version of the SVN client are you using?

Comment: See edit for SVN client version.  Because I'm using the svn commands and not TortoiseProc.exe commands, is the SVN client version going to affect my commands?  From the documentation, these are two isolated sets of commands or two isolated APIs.  I guess what I'm wondering is if I even need TortoiseSVN (SVN client) on my local machine if these commands are being run?  That's something I would have to test.

Comment: Using svn.exe instead of TortoiseProc.exe is the correct move. As long as you're using the version that came with Tortoise, you'll be fine. I just wanted to make sure that you had a version that supported everything. You need *a* Subversion client (obviously), and IMHO the easiest way to get a good copy installed for the command line on Windows is to use the one bundled with Tortoise.

Comment: Okay.  I didn't know the difference.  I just saw they had slightly different commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because `NZ` doesn't exist yet - there's nothing there *to* update in the first place. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Tell `svn update` to create all necessary parent directories:

   `svn update --set-depth empty --parents _TEST/NZ/F_CORPORATION_SIZE`
2. Do it in steps, one per directory level

   `svn update --set-depth empty _TEST/NZ`
   `svn update --set-depth empty _TEST/NZ/F_CORPORATION_SIZE`
   `svn update --set-depth empty _TEST/NZ/F_COVERAGE_MEMBER`

Comment: That worked great.  I just made one small change to the last two commands.  I replaced "empty" with "immediates" to pull children files of each folder... regarding my note, "Ideally I would like the files under those two folders in addition (--set-depth immediates), but I have not gotten that far."